# How to know who and when files and folders have been deleted in CentOS?

Tags: centos, cpanel, whm, computer-forensics

Some files and folders have been deleted on a web server, How to know how delete them and when? I checked the Raw Access logs but I couldn't find some thing could help.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find to search by modification time. For example, to find files touched in the last 3 days:

```
 find /home/user -mtime -3
```

For "older than 3 days", use **+3**

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

second command

```
history
```

.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to look for info on the deleted data are the FTP server logs as well:

```
/var/log/messages
```

You can also look through the cPanel access log in case the files/folders were deleted via cPanel's File Manager:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/logs/access_log
```